# Chrome Extension content script matcher with # (hash) in URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

1. What does a slash after a # (hash) in a URL (ex. https://connect.monstercat.com/#music/catalog/) generally do? Is it processable with the server or only with the client (=javascript)?
2. How can I match this URL in a Chrome Extension manifest?

I hope this question is at least partially understandable...

Comment: The first part of the question was answered thousands of times over the years on the internet, so instead of asking it *now* [use search](https://www.google.com/#q=url%20hash%20purpose).

Comment: @wOxxOm I know the purpose of "hash" but I did not know that there can be a slash + more after the hash, and I wanted to know what it means/ you can do with it

Comment: Everything after `#` is a fragment identifier, this is clearly stated in the description on wiki and w3c an chrome docs. So there are no special restrictions on slashes and whatnot.

Comment: Ah, and anyway the 1st question is too broad and can't be mixed with the specific and code-based 2nd one. If you want an expanded answer with examples and so on, then ask a separate question and this time make sure to mention what you know already and what you would like to see in an answer so that it won't be marked as a duplicate.